# How do I access the contents of my Amazon shopping cart?

Tags: amazon

I'm creating a script that injects helpful data into the amazon shopping cart page. For this, I want to basically query the items a customer has already added to their shopping cart.

I know this is possible because the [share-a-cart](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/share-a-cart-for-amazon/peiobddfomnijgoblelfdmjblplojcoe) extension does it.

So, how do I programmatically access the shopping cart list on Amazon?

Edit: This was closed as off-topic correctly. However, if you're building something similar, the answer gave me pointed me to the right direction, and I solved my problem by injecting a snippet of JavaScript to the user's page, which let me scrape and process their checkout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the context of where your script will live. In an extension, I have elevated priviledges to access websites on behalf of the user. When I use this model, I get access to the DOM of the shopping cart page and I parse it to retrieve the contents. Heres the code I use: https://github.com/fixanoid/amazon-share-a-cart/blob/master/chrome/lib/injects/inject-cart.js